# Large Language Models for Translating Natural Language to Mathematical Models - Suitable Venues?

Tags: modeling, journals

I'm currently working on a paper that investigates the capabilities of Large Language Models (like OpenAI's GPT variants) to understand and write mathematical models based solely on natural language descriptions of optimization problems.

Given the multidisciplinary nature of this research at the intersection of OR and NLP, I'm seeking suggestions for a suitable venue/journal/conference to present this work. I believe many in the OR community would find the results intriguing, especially with the potential to reshape how we formulate and communicate optimization problems.

Has anyone seen similar works or know of venues where such research is particularly welcomed? Your insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://nl4opt.github.io/

Comment: @RobPratt, Thanks for sharing this. I know ML/NLP venues like NeurIPS, ACL, EMNLP, AAAI, etc., might be good choices. However, I'm looking for venues more targeted towards the OR community

Answer (score 2):

A good start to reaching the OR community would be publishing in an INFORMS journal. Among those, I suspect the [INFORMS Journal on Computing](https://pubsonline.informs.org/journal/ijoc) might be the best fit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Informs Journal on Computing looks like a good fit.